# removing ticklabels python

Tags: pandas

I am plotting a multipanel figure in python using a pandas dataframe. I have used the shorter version:

```
df1_5.plot(subplots=True, sharex=True);
```

which removes xtick labels on all but the bottom figure in a 5 row by 1 column figure format.

However in order to customize the plots, I was more explicit about how I plotted and used the following code:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=1, figsize=(8, 5))
df11_15['V11'].plot(ax=axes[0], ylim=(0, 7)); axes[0].set_title('V1')
df11_15['V12'].plot(ax=axes[1], ylim=(0, 7)); axes[1].set_title('V12')
df11_15['V13'].plot(ax=axes[2], ylim=(-0.5, 1.0)); axes[2].set_title('V13')
df11_15['V14'].plot(ax=axes[3], ylim=(-0.5,0.5)); axes[3].set_title('V14')
df11_15['V15'].plot(ax=axes[4], ylim=(-0.5, 0.5)); axes[4].set_title('V15')
```

I would like to remove the xticklabels from the upper four plots. Can you tell me how to do this?

I tried:

```
axes[3].set_axisticklabels()
```

but was told there was no attribute error named `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```py
for label in ax[3].get_xticklabels():
    label.set_visible(False)
```

For completeness I will also provide example on how this works in a loop

```py
# generate 2x4 matrix of subplots
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=2)
for i,ax in enumerate(fig.axes):
    # fill histograms with random numbers
    ax.hist(np.random.normal(size = 100), bins=20)
    # set the same xlim so that making labels invisible makes sense
    ax.set_xlim([-4,4])
    # make labels invisible only if "ax" is not in the last row 
    if not ax.is_last_row():
        for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
            label.set_visible(False)
```

Comment: This is great, thanks!  I like the efficiency of the loop. And I realized that I can call it on a line-by-line basis with, for e.g.,: axes[0].set_xticklabels(' '); axes[0].set_xlabel(' ')